# Polymer-IE11 compatibility, new get keyword before function name

Tags: polymer, internet-explorer-11

My website works fine in Chrome.
I am trying to get it working in IE11 as well.

But see an error message at this line of code.

[image]

When i go in, i see that it is due to below line of code in paper-button element.

[image]

From past experience i know that polymer doesn't work in IE11 if i don't use colon separator and use function keyword to declare a function in javascript. e.g. as shown below.

```
_onDownKey: function(event) {}
```

I am using Polymer 1.9.3

Need guidance on understanding this new get keyword.
What is this new get keyword in front of the function name, what it does and how to make polymer elements compatible with IE11 as well if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Information about get can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). Obviously IE is not able to use this, thats why you have to transpile your code from es6 to javascript/es5. You can use [polymer build](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/build-for-production) for this. Also if you transpiled your code and if you have included the [webcomponents](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) polyfill it will work in IE11. Hope this helps!